# PHP, MySQL, Google Maps Questions

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps

I'm attempting to build a web app and I've run into a bit of a wall. I'm not asking for anyone to hold my hand through making this, just some advice and a push in the right direction.

So, I'm trying to build an app that uses the Google Maps API to display a map of local parks near you and allow people to post pickup games (informal sporting events) for a specific time at a specific park. Simple enough right?

So far I've created a database with a table of local parks (columns: name, longitude, latitude) and a php script that takes that table and turns it into an XML file that the map uses to plot the points of the parks. I've also created a form that uses php to insert new data into the table and thus create a new park marker on the map.

This has all gone well so far but I'm just not sure how to proceed. I think I want to create a table 'games' (columns: sport, time, park(?)) but I'm not sure if that will work. Will I be able to setup a relationship between the 'parks' and 'games' table so that many games belong to a park? If so, how would I map those games? Does my thinking make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'll create `games` table with `sport_id | time | park_id` columns, then `game` entity will be related to `park` entity by `one-to-many` relation. It means that one park handles `0..Many` games and one game always belongs to one park.

So, this is suitable solution for your issue. It fits your expectations.

Additional info about relations: [Cardinality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality_%28data_modeling%29)

Comment: So MySQL creates the relationship automatically when _id is appended?

Comment: Or would I have to manually create a relation between the id column on parks and the park_id column of games? If so, any good resources to learn more on how?

Comment: Nope, mysql does not create relation automatically. To keep integrity you have to manually create foreign keys constraint: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html